# Why isn't the status bar adjusting the color of its text to match my UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that uses a navigation bar with a dark gray background color and a white title. According to [this article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/), under "UINavigationController and the iOS7 Status Bar", it says that it should that as long as I am using a navigation controller, the status bar should automatically adjust its text color to match it. Here is a screenshot of the top of my app:

[image]

As you can see, the navigation controller's title was set to white, so shouldn't the status bar be set to white too? Here's my code for the navigation controller's color adjustment:

```
UINavigationController* navStack = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainFeed];

navStack.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20/255.0f green:20/255.0f blue:20/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
navStack.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[navStack.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add this in:

```
navStack.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

What that article says is a bit misleading.

Comment: Yes, this works. Took a while to find as well. Lot's of confusion with iOS7 status bar. I now can set a barTintColor to whatever, and still have white status text and icons.